# select rows with duplicate observations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a large dataset and there are a few duplicates in my index. I'd like to (perhaps visually) check what these duplicated rows are like and then decide which one to drop. Is there a way that I can select the slice of the dataframe that have duplicated indices (or duplicates in any columns)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `pandas.duplicated`  and then slice it using a `boolean`. For more information on any method or advanced features, I would advise you to always check in its **docstring.**

Well, this would solve the case for you:

```
df[df.duplicated('Column Name', keep=False) == True]
```

Here,
**keep=False** will return all those rows having duplicate values in that column.

Comment: thanks, and for mulitple columns use subset=[col1,col2,...] ref.: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Answer (score 5):

use `duplicated` method of `DataFrame`:

```
df.duplicated(cols=[...])
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

**EDIT**

You can use:

```
df[df.duplicated(cols=[...]) | df.duplicated(cols=[...], take_last=True)]
```

or, you can use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby([...]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] > 1)
```

or `apply`:

```
df.groupby([...], group_keys=False).apply(lambda df:df if df.shape[0] > 1 else None)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. But it only returns the first (or last) row of the duplicated rows. Is it possible to return all the duplicated rows?

Comment: @ZhenSun, I added a method that using `groupby`, please check it.

Comment: Thanks! This is smart. Unfortunately they just take too long. On my dataset of about 4 million rows, they took forever to return the results..